# Cannot Get Conditions for Rule with BigCommerce API

Tags: php, api, bigcommerce

I am trying to get the sku_id from the conditions in a chosen rule on a product.

```
$conditions = $rule->conditions();
foreach ($conditions as $condition) {
    $rule_sku_ids = $condition->condition->sku_id;
}
```

I seem to get nothing returned from this, not even an error message. Has anyone done this with the API before and can show me if I have gone wrong where.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved after contacting BigCommerce Support.

There is a bug within the conditions function in Rule.php.

Find this function:

```
public function conditions()
{
    $conditions = Client::getCollection($this->fields->conditions->resource, 'RuleCondition');

    foreach ($conditions as $condition) {
        $condition->product_id = $this->product_id;
    }

    return $conditions;
}
```

and change it to this:

```
public function conditions()
{
    return $this->fields->conditions;
}
```

This solves the problem.